# How to make less output persistent on the terminal, after quitting less?

Tags: less-unix

On my old system (Linux Mint 18.3), every time I used the less command and quitted (q), the last viewed page of less remained on the terminal (bash) view

On my new system (Min 19.3), when I quit 'less', everything fades, as if less was never opened (similar to what happens with 'nano' command, for example)

Is there a way to make less behave like in my old system? It was very useful when working e.g. with git logs

Comment: This question better fits https://superuser.com/. I voted to close and migrate it there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `man less`:

> `-X` or `--no-init`: Disables sending the termcap initialization and deinitialization strings to the terminal.  This is  sometimes  desirable  if
>                 the deinitialization string does something unnecessary, like clearing the screen.

Comment: Thanks! I looked through the manual options, but this one is not an obvious one at first glance